# SharePoint List calculated value

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2013

I am using SP lists to maintain users PTO and a Master list to forecast utilization hours based on their goals as follows. I am on SharePoint 2013, what calculated formulas can I use to get the Forecast hours in the Master list?  Thanks much!
Included are sample PTO & Master List

[MasterList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3mEe.png)
[PTOList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHqM9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid that we can not achieve this with calculated column. We can not get look up value in calculated column formula. It is even more impossible for us to get the sum of all hours based on time and a specific person.
[image]

I recommend you to create an event receiver on PTO_List(item added) to achieve this.